# Delete field from Firebase database (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using recyclerView, each row represents a stock, and its connected to a Firebase accout that has users auth, and everytime a user is created i add him to my Firebase databse (when they sign up my Firebase account), each user has "user_stocks" (child) field and i made a longClickListener which deletes a row in my stock list, problem is that i need to also delete this stock in the users account:
[image]

i cant find a way to delete the stock from the Firebase database:

```
    public void deleteFromFirebase(String user_id) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child(user_id);

        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
               //No metter what i did, it did not delete from fb
            }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
    }
});
}
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place null in that child as a value

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id).setValue(null);
```

**Update**

Deleting by value

```
public void deleteFromFirebase(String user_id,final String stockName) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users").child(user_id).child("user_stocks");

        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot stock : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(stock.getValue().equals(stockName))
                    stock.getRef().removeValue();
               }
            } 

    @Override 
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value 
    } 
}); 
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work, also would it delete the entry or just change the value to null?

Comment: @Coder123 It would delete the entry.

Comment: @Coder123 also, your listener there will not fire every time the value changes, only once. Check the firebase console for the real value

Comment: real value of what?

Comment: Updated value after delete

Comment: it doesnt change, i also tried:

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
myRef.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id).child(user_stocks).child("Google").setValue(null); 
also doesnt work

Comment: That because Google is the value, not the key.

Comment: So i do i delete only "Google" stock? In your line of code it will delete all the user stock, or am i wrong?

Comment: If you want to delete the user's entire entry use: 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id).setValue(null);
If you want to delete only the google stock use: 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id).child("users_stocks").child("6").setValue(null);

Comment: Oh know i see, is it also possible to delete by value instead of the key?